# Twitter API, Adding Hyperlinks

Tags: php, html, twitter

I'm using the Twitter API to grab the last 3 tweets of my timeline using "statuses/user_timeline" function.  It grabs the tweets and sends the response, but I need to inject hyperlinks for the HTML in my web page.  The problem is the Microsoft characters are throwing off the indices for the location of the links.

```
Join us at TOMORROW at @SugarLandtxgov's “Art In The Park” and see the 4  
#PODA2 containers all in one place! http://t.co/leqtqhdAiI #HOUarts

[text] => Join us at TOMORROW at @SugarLandtxgov's “Art In The Park” and
see the 4 #PODA2 containers all in one place! http://t.co/leqtqhdAiI 
#HOUarts

[url] => http://t.co/leqtqhdAiI
[expanded_url] => http://www.artshound.com/event/detail/441912984
[display_url] => artshound.com/event/detail/4…
[indices] => Array
       (
              [0] => 109
              [1] => 131
       )
```

This is the output after I inject the hyperlinks into the string:

```
Join us at TOMORROW at @SugarLandtxgov's “Art In The Park” and see the 4 
#PODA2 containers all in one pla<a href="http://t.co/leqtqhdAiI" 
target="_blank">ce! http://t.co/leqtqh</a>dAiI #HOUarts
```

Comment: My first impression is that it could be a counting error with multibyte characters (ie. UTF-16 instead of UTF-8) but the link href is matched correctly, so maybe not?. Can you show us your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to explicitly set the encoding and use multi-byte string functions:

```
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
echo mb_substr($text, 0, 109) . '<a href="' . $link . '">' . mb_substr($text, 109, 131-109) . '</a>' . mb_substr($text, 131);
```